# HTML markup and special characters in image descriptions

Tags: html, typo3

In TYPO3 I used to add HTML markup in the "description (caption)" field of image elements in the backend. Since a recent update (now to version 6.2.17 but maybe already earlier) the HTML markup is shown as plain text in the frontend; the angle brackets are escaped e.g. as `&lt;`. Also `&shy;` is escaped and shown as plain text. How can I get TYPO3 to recognize HTML markup in image descriptions again? There is no button to switch to HTML editing there.

Answer (score 1):

I have learnt from another resource that with version 6.2.16 a vulnerability was fixed; see bulletin https://typo3.org/teams/security/security-bulletins/typo3-core/typo3-core-sa-2015-013/. Adding

```
tt_content.image.20.caption.1.1 {
    htmlSpecialChars = 0
}
```

to the TypoScript template allows using HTML markup.

Comment: ... and introduces the vulnerability again!

Comment: There is only a vulnerability if the editors abuse this possibility. I fully trust my editor - which is myself. By the way, I believe that a simple version update (which might be installed by many users just with a click, without reading the release notes) is an inappropriate way for introducing such a significant modification.

Comment: You are required to read the upgrade notices (which highlight this change) and security  updates can always be breaking.